# Socket.connect doesn't work after a disconnect

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to reconnect after a disconnect. However, I'm able to see the "try reconnect <><><><><><><><>" print, but the socket is never able to reconnect. Why?

````
    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('socket connected ====================');
      reconnectTimer && clearInterval(reconnectTimer);
      dispatch(updateConnectingStatus(false));
      dispatch(updateSocketStatus(true));
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', reason => {
      console.log('socket disconnect *******************');
      dispatch(updateConnectingStatus(false));
      dispatch(updateSocketStatus(false));

      // reconnect.
      reconnectTimer = setInterval(() => {
        console.log('try reconnect <><><><><><><><>');
        socket.connect();
      }, 1500);
    });```
````

Comment: How are you initializing `socket`? If you used `io()`, reconnections should be automatic.